# Showing iframes in android webview correctly

Tags: android, iframe, webview

I want to show some html content in webView. Here is my code:

```
String htmlContent = "...";  // some content here       

webViewContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webViewContent.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webViewContent.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webViewContent.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webViewContent.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
webViewContent.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webViewContent.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
webViewContent.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webViewContent.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.background_final_page));
webViewContent.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlContent , "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

It shows text and images well, but when i have iframe in htmlContent , for example

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=link" width="100%"></iframe>
```

webView shows iframe not correctly,  with cropped height.When i added height="100%" to iframe code, it has no result. When i set height=600 or height=400, it works, but i cannt know in advance height size of iframe. 
So, how i can to fix it?

Comment: Found any solution to this?